# Auto correction , auto complete features

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

Hii ,

We see suggestions when we type a word in Ms-word , google etc... How do they do that ?

I would like to know how the techniqueslike auto correct , auto complete , spell checking etc.. are performed . HOw are the words actually stored... what algorithms are followed ... ???

Any links that suggest a possible way are welcome,

Comment: Not C++, but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524264/algorithms-and-data-structures-best-suited-for-a-spell-checker-dictionary-and-a

Comment: It simply searches a set of stored earlier entries. The main difficulty, I guess, is to correctly determine the context (e.g. for filling in a field in web page in a browser) to determine earlier entries for that context. Algorithms & data structure for the retrieval itself are (can be) trivial since the lists are very short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some data structures that are especially useful for working with (and finding) strings.

- [Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)
- [Suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)
- [Directed acyclic word graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)
- [Suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)
- [Patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)

These can be especially useful for auto-completion.

[Here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)'s a simple spell checker written in Python with a bit of digression on how it works.

In order to build a dictionary, you could "parse" e.g. wikipedia to collect known words.