# Programming Interview. Implementing Auto Complete

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

When you typed in a letter on a text box, it will get the list of users that starts with the first few characters you typed in. I tried to store the data on a hash map, with the keys containing 0 to n letters from each entry. So for example, for Chris, I have an entry in the hash map with keys:

C
Ch
Chr
Chri
Chris

This is very efficient in terms of how fast it is but inefficient in terms of memory. The question is: how will you efficiently implement it? Since I indicated that it is a programming interview question, what is the data structure suitable to efficiently implement the feature?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I guess the answer is "Trie" but it's hard to know without a question.

Comment: How to implement it? Is it not obvious? @nem

Comment: Q&A is the format of StackExchange & stackoverflow. If nothing else, following [ask] increases the probability of getting answers, even helpful ones.

Comment: I already have the question. What else seems to be missing? @greybeard

Comment: - (for room for improvement) descriptions of or links to findings from your search for answers; title (one of _my_ pet peeves …) + clearly states the problem domain - leaves open the particular problem/question; + include relevant tags; proof read - my bet is you missed out at least on taking a deep breath (or otherwise your mind off the question) before proof reading. If you get feed-back regarding a post of yours, edit the post (and comment comments only where that seems _useful_ in addition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question which is answered by community (user:phimuemue) : [Auto correction , auto complete features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014732/auto-correction-auto-complete-features)

I'm just copying from this post, you can find details and links in this post.

- Tries
- Suffix trees
- Directed acyclic word graphs
- Suffix array
- Patricia trie

Answer (score 2):

Store the data in a tree instead of a hashmap. You can navigate the tree as far as the user has typed, then the sub-tree will contain all possible options for what they could be typing.

Take this example tree.

```
          C
         / \
        A   U
       /|   |\
      R B   B L
     /         \
    D           T
```

Suppose that the user has typed a C and an A. That would mean the following portion of the graph contains possible auto-complete suggestions.

```
          C
         / 
        A     CA
       / \ 
      R   B   CAR CAB
     /         
    D         CARD
```

It can still make for quite an expansive structure, but it is quite efficient to traverse, and reasonably efficient to store, as well.

Comment: The first example contains a cycle - what do you call a tree?

Comment: It would be a cycle, I suppose, except it's directed. I'll go ahead and split it out to make it more classically tree-like.