# Optimal physical orderings of nodes

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, tree

First, read this:
[TPT paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W/W09/W09-1505.pdf)
I was wondering what other options might exist for arranging nodes to boost performance.  Anything from post-parent order in a byte array, like TPT's, to something more like a k-order b-tree; I'm wondering what good options are known at the moment?

A bit more on the problem:
I have an extremely fast way of finding elements within a sparse set, given some concept of adjacency to a given pointer.  I was wondering how I could best take advantage of this in storing a patricia trie.

You can make assumptions about whether the trie will be random-access, read only, write-seldom, or add-only.  Please note them if you do, but I've actually used a TPT and the gains were pretty significant so I'm willing to consider certain constraints.

**Update**

I guess in some senses this was a little unclear.  What I'm looking for here is ways of arranging things in memory that optimize one performance metric or another.  The TPTs, through some tricks, use node order to optimize disk reads and space-per-node.  I'm curious about:

Total deletion, where the structure is removed from memory entirely.
Inserts, particularly in densely populated structures.
Deletes, again, particularly in densely populated structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DAWG or a minimal DFA (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524264/algorithms-and-data-structures-best-suited-for-a-spell-checker-dictionary-and-a) or the paper "[How to squeeze a lexicon](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.6055)") may be even better than a TPT because the totel size is smaller.

Comment: That's really interesting!  I can't see any way though, to implement a meaningful map via a DAWG without compromising much of what makes them efficient.  I suppose that each node could contain a hash-bucket, or something similar, but I am intensely dubious about this.

Comment: In the lexicon paper the minimal DFA is weighted: Every state has a weight, if you add the weights along the path to a final state you get a unique number for every word (in fact you get a minimal perfact hash number) which you can use as an index into an array with your associated information. By adding another level of indirection you can associate an arbitrary number of items to one word.

Comment: I will think deeply on this, but that is incredibly clever.