# preprocessing dictionary

Tags: algorithm

How to preprocess dictionary so that below operations are best supported
a) search in dictiorry
b) given a string find all valid anagrams in a dictionary
c) typing prefix of a valid string suggests valid words

Will trie do the trick?

Comment: See the question and my answer: [Optimal physical orderings of nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327755/optimal-physical-orderings-of-nodes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a) and (c), use an ordinary trie.
For (b), sort each word, and build a trie with the sorted words, but associate each leaf in the trie with a list of the (un-sorted) words that correspond to it.